# Simple hexadecimal to 2s complement question

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

From 2.5.1 in [this paper](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf), how is

$p$ = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFE FFFFFFFF 00000000 00000000 FFFFFFFF

= $2^{384} − 2^{128} − 2^{96} + 2^{32} − 1$

derived?

Comment: What are you asking ? The conversion ? If so that's just hexadecimal representation of a positive number (there is no two's complement)

Comment: Using big endian representation, of course. You don't have to derive anything: [WolframAlpha al rescate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hex(2%5E384+−+2%5E128+−+2%5E96+%2B+2%5E32+−+1)).

Answer (score 0):

To have a signed 2-complement representation then you have to left pad the value with a single 00 valued byte. Generally API's will already view hexadecimals as positive unless they are preceded with a minus sign.

E.g. in Java:

```
// read value from string
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("FF...FF");
// signed byte representation, with additional zero valued byte to the left
byte[] encX = x.toByteArray();
```